# jCrop HTML5 Canvas Base64

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, base64, jcrop

I'm trying to work with `jCrop` and `canvas`.

Instead of sending the image to the server and back again with a cropped image, I'm trying to crop it directly, using canvas, because with the result, I transform the crop in a base64 image and send to the server.

I have [an example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s39P3/).

I crop the image then convert in canvas but I cant transform image in base64. The below error appears:

```
"SecurityError: The operation is insecure."
```

I have tried with..

```
console.log(canvas.toDataURL());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, this problem is due to [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (cross-origin resource sharing) requirements not being fulfilled.

To avoid this you can either:

- Serve the image being cropped from the same origin as the page
- Request cross-origin use by supplying `crossOrigin` property to the image
- Use a proxy to serve the image from the external site through your server (in which case much of the point is lost doing everything locally).

In addition:

- When testing, don't use the local `file://` protocol but a light local server (ie. [Mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/))

If not you will get an security error every time you use `toDataURL` (or `getImageData`).

About requesting CORS usage from external servers: you can only *request* such use but it's up to the server to grant the permission or not.

To request either:

```
<img src="..." crossOrigin="anonymous" >
```

or from JavaScript:

```
var img = new Image;

img.onload = handleOnLoad;
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = '...';
```

If denied the image won't load at all.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue. Problem is when you have the canvas with something on it already then put something else on it it becomes tainted. my workaround was to remove the canvas element and replace it then place a new image on it.